# Hyperlinks sent tp @Facebook.com accounts changed to broken fbsbx.com redirect links

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, message

Almost any hyperlink in an email sent to an @Facebook.com address is broken with a fbsbx.com redirect link. If you change the fbsbx.com in that link to Facebook.com, then the link works, so it's something about that domain. 
For example, when I email myself this link: http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-57504786-1/the-weird-world-where-3d-printing-and-art-collide/ 
When I click through it as an incoming Facebook message it's become: http://fbsbx.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.cnet.com%2F8301-17938_105-57504786-1%2Fthe-weird-world-where-3d-printing-and-art-collide%2F&h=rAQEQCCGn&s=1
That just takes me to a "Not Found" page.

So far I haven't been able to find a work-around.

This is especially a problem for me given that my emergency apps allows people to notify their friends or their emergencies via Facebook message. Those Facebook messages contain links to the live session, but Facebook is breaking those links. We send the links by sending them as @Facebook.com emails. The messages get through, but the links are broken. Fixing this is crucial for my app.

Comment: Well, I’d say file a bug report with Facebook. Btw., apps are _not_ supposed to use those email addresses to contact users according to Platform Policies …

Comment: Just had this problem with a friend using Internet Explorer on Windows (7, I think). Logged into Facebook using Chrome on the same laptop and the link was fine, as it was for me using Firefox on XP.